# Decorators are not valid here, biome(parse)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, biomejs

The default [biomejs](https://github.com/biomejs/biome) configuration (or linting rule) raises an error on every decorator defined in NestJS resolvers:

```
Decorators are not valid here. biome(parse)
```

How to ignore this rule globally?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the block:

```json
    "javascript": {
        "parser": {
            "unsafeParameterDecoratorsEnabled": true
        }
    },
```

to your biome configuration. [Biome's docs](https://biomejs.dev/reference/configuration/#javascriptparserunsafeparameterdecoratorsenabled)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the rule `unsafeParameterDecoratorsEnabled` to true works to prevent the errors when running biome through the CLI, but they still show up when using the plugin. I haven't found a solution for that.

```
"javascript": {
    "parser": {
        "unsafeParameterDecoratorsEnabled": true
    }
},
```